# Ag-grid angular set id in column

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am trying to set id as a column in ag-grid. However I'd starts from 0 not 1. Am trying to increment but it's not working. Below is the code

```
header name :id,
cellRenderer : function (params) {
  return params.node.id + 1;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean a value of the data in your row? Then use params.node.data.id... or do you mean you want a row counter? Then use params.node.rowIndex + 1

Answer (score 0):

params.rowIndex +1 , solved my question